# Save results of cmp() to file

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, file, io

I'm trying to run a three way comparison on some lists, Then store the difference if found to a file. Below is the code i have so far. I'm having trouble figuring out how to save the missing file(if found) to the text file.

I also know the comparison code is not optimal but i'm new to programming and just trying different things out. If anyone has a better Idea let me know. I'm here to learn.

**Comparison Code**

```
def three_way_compare(startup, running, archive):
    if cmp(startup, archive) and cmp(running, archive) != 0:
        print "Archive File Missing: "
        print set(startup)^set(archive)
    elif cmp(startup, archive) != 0:
        print "Startup File Missing: "
        print "File missing: " 
        print set(startup)^set(archive)
    elif cmp(running, archive) != 0:
        print "Running File Missing: "
        print set(running)^set(archive)
    elif cmp(running, startup) != 0:
        print "Running and Startup do not match"
        print "Missing Files: " 
        print set(running)^set(startup)
    else:
        print "All Files match"
```

**Write Files Code**

```
def write_diff_file():
    from datetime import datetime
    datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    f = open('filediff_' + datestring + '.txt', 'w')
    f.name
```

Something like,

if three_way_compare == True # returns a difference
then write file with current date with the difference found

I think i've solved it by doing this.

**Updated Comparison Code:**

```
def three_way_compare(startup, running, archive):
    isdiff = True
    if cmp(startup, archive) and cmp(running, archive) != 0:
        print "Archive File Missing: "
        compareset = set(startup)^set(archive)
    elif cmp(startup, archive) != 0:
        print "Startup File Missing: " 
        compareset = set(startup)^set(archive)
    elif cmp(running, archive) != 0:
        print "Running File Missing: "
        compareset = set(running)^set(archive)
    elif cmp(running, startup) != 0:
        print "Running and Startup do not match"
        compareset = set(running)^set(startup)
    else:
        print "All Files match" 
        isdiff = False
    if isdiff == True:
        write_diff_file(compareset)
```

**Updated Write Files Code:**

```
def write_diff_file(x):
    from datetime import datetime
    datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    with open('filediff_' + datestring + '.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(x))
        f.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
content = 'what I want to save'
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as logfile:
    logfile.write(content)  # the 'with' keyword will close the file for you
```

Comment: That would work under a normal write. But i want the file to write as a certain file name and only write if a difference is found. With the difference being what is written to the file.